# How to achieve Peek Calendar like scrolling behavior on UITableView or UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, uiscrollview, scroll

Does anyone have suggestions on how to achieve this kinda animation in either UITableView or UICollectionView (animation below)? It also seems to work properly with ScrollToTop behavior (by not going into the grey areas).

[image: image credit: www.raywenderlich.com/72166/best-ios-7-animations-call-nominees]

I'm thinking the new cells are added after the resistance animation concludes. It's interesting how everything stays in place though. Any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: Did you implement this design ? I would also use it into my app and can't find any information on the web...

Comment: @ArnaudNelissen sorry - i ended up ditching the design altogether.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar as UIRefreshControl. Instead of showing activity indicator, it has custom animation. You can sub-class UIRefreshControl and set background as Blue (Dark Blue?). So when you scroll down you won't see grey area (I assume this is your question).

Once the UIRefreshControl trigged its action of Value Changed, you do the animation that move the calendar down.

http://www.jackrabbitmobile.com/design/ios-custom-pull-to-refresh-control/

You can check this code, hope that could help. :)

Comment: Would you place the calendar into a new view controller or use it as a simple view ?

Comment: @ArnaudNelissen I think a simple view should be ok, cuz I implemented similar stuff with two views and use custom UIRefreshControl to switch between views.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will try to implement this asap !